# T-SQL check if primary key exists in duplicated table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge, primary-key

I ran into a problem where I need to figure out if a primary key value already exists in my table.

I transfer data from an ERP system into my SQL Server database, this data is split in many tables all have different clustered PK.

To prevent dataloss, caused through locked data, I build a way that dublicates all tables and copies data from table a to table b in my SQL Server.

To have better performance I only transfer x month back of data from the ERP and not always all data. Plus there could be changes in the new data that I need to track.

My question is, is there a way, that I can dynamicaly copy only data, that is new and update data that got changed?

Comment: You mean duplicate (with **p** not **b**). Also "if Primary Key exists" is simply a matter of using `WHERE NOT EXISTS (...)` for which there are many existing questions you can consider. ***However:*** you go on to say you want to update changed data. This is an entirely separate question. Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the SSIS you can quickly create an ssis package to  implement Slowly changing dimension..

Comment: i get the data with ssis, but the package is already build so detailed that if i would build in a lookup table or something i had to change more than i could concidering the budget. sadly.

Comment: refer the below link   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/slowly-changing-dimension-transformation

Answer (score 0):

My question is, is there a way, that I can dynamicaly copy only data, that is new and update data that got changed?

**YES**

First My technique To do That :

**- Make a dynamic Query**

The Main idea is to check if the id is already Not exists OR Exists It depends on script

True :  exists (Insert)

False :  Not exists (Update)

Now : Dynamic Query Like This

```
select 
 'Begin' + Char(13) + Char(10) -- Now i do this becouse i well declare a variblae So every time generate make a seperator to avoid error 

 'Declare @ID Int '+ Char(13) + Char(10)
'select @ID =' + A.ID  -- now make Select Fields or supQuery To GEt the ID From Old Data Base 

'if Not EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM MyTable WHERE ID =@ID  ) ' + Char(13) + Char(10) -- @ID Come From OLD Data Base And i Check it in the new Data base
'Insert into MyTable (Fields) '+ Char(13) + Char(10)
'Values ('+ Char(13) + Char(10)
           +' '+ '@ID'+ Char(13) + Char(10)
           +','+ Cast(Isnull(''''+A.Nvarchar(50)+''''  ,'New')  As NVarChar(100))   + Char(13) + Char(10)--EXP With Nvarchar
           +','+          IsNull(Cast(A.INT || Decimal .ETC    As NVarChar(10))          ,'0' )      + Char(13) + Char(10)--EXP With INT
                   +') ; '+ Char(13) + Char(10)

 'End' + Char(13) + Char(10)
 'Else '          + Char(13) + Char(10)
 'Update MyTable  Set '     + Char(13) + Char(10)
+' '+'ID = @ID'             + Char(13) + Char(10)
+','+ 'Nvarchar = '++','+ Cast(Isnull(''''+A.Nvarchar(50)+''''  ,'New')  As NVarChar(100))   + Char(13) + Char(10)--EXP With Nvarchar
+','+ 'INT      = ' +','+          IsNull(Cast(A.INT || Decimal .ETC    As NVarChar(10))          ,'0' )+ Char(13) + Char(10)--EXP With INT

+ ' Where ID ='+''''+A.ID+'''; '  + Char(13) + Char(10) -- Dont Forget This : that make the Select Genertate ROw By Row
+ 'GO '  + Char(13) + Char(10)

+' End ; '  + Char(13) + Char(10)
FROM MyTable As A
```

NOTE : U Run This Script From OLD DB And Run IT in the New DB

I hope this help u as u don't Give me an EXP

Comment: yeah i have something more or less simular but do you might know if there is a table, that holds all constrains with their clustered columns per table?

Comment: okay i got it `SELECT tab.TABLE_SCHEMA, tab.TABLE_NAME,  Col.Column_Name from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab, 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col 
WHERE 
    Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name
    AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name
    AND Constraint_Type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME`

Comment: As U Similar like me
- Dont Forget the FK May be it have a new Key also 
So U Can Do it as below 

or if u have the tow database in same machine 

I think u can use merge it well more easy Coding

Answer (score 0):

refer the below link which SCD
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/slowly-changing-dimension-transformation

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using dynamic SQL + XML Path.

I just got all the keys I need from Information Schema. Then I put together in 2 columns `TableName` and `Filter`, with a subselect + XML path I managed to have the `TableName` with a comma-separated list of filters for my join.

This I put into a temp table combined it with dynamic SQL and it works.

Thanks for help :)